# Blocked css/js resources in China

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have some sites that load correctly in Europe/America/etc.
But for users from China they always load unpredictable or don't load.
After debugging with someone from China we figured that main CSS file (it's Angular app) isn't reaching user's browser.
This CSS is loaded from Nginx server that is on AWS EC2 with default region in Ireland.

Should we have this EC2 replicated to AWS China region?

Has anyone faced similar issues? How did you guys solved them?

Comment: If it's a css/js that doesn't change much, you could copy the css/js file(s) along with your site files (each time you upload a new version of your site). China, indeed, blocks a lot of stuff... (and replicating to a local server in China should have it work also)

Comment: @e2-e4, I think this is what we will end up doing. Since we're on AWS, will have to use their replication mechanisms.